# Query and Mutate GraphQL from Lambda function in AWS-Amplify using Cognito for auth

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I created a GraphQL api via the `amplify api add` command and added the schema below. I'm using cognito for auth.

```
type User @model
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }]) {
  id: ID!

  videos: [Video!] @connection(keyName: "videosByUser", fields: ["id"])
  adverts: [Advert] @connection(keyName:"advertsByUser", fields: ["id"])
}

type Video @model
  @key(name: "videosByUser", fields: ["userId"])
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, operations: [create, update, delete] }]) {

  id: ID!
  title: String!
  description: String!

  size: Float!
  length: Float!
  hashMarks: [Float!]!

  userId: ID!
  # bidrectional connection, if needed
  # user: User! @connection(fields: ["userId"])

  adverts: [VideoAdverts!] @connection(keyName: "advertsByVideo", fields: ["id"])
  streamingLink: AWSURL
}

type VideoAdverts @model(queries: null)
  @key(name: "advertsByVideo", fields: ["videoId", "advertId"])
  @key(name: "videosByAdvert", fields: ["advertId", "videoId"]) {

  id: ID!
  videoId: ID!
  advertId: ID!

  video: Video! @connection(fields: ["videoId"])
  advert: Advert! @connection(fields: ["advertId"])
}

type Advert @model
  @key(name: "advertsByUser", fields: ["userId"])
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, operations: [create, update, delete] }]) {

  id: ID!
  title: String!
  description: String!

  size: Float!
  length: Float!

  creatorId: ID!
  # bidrectional connection, if needed
  # creator: Creator! @connection(fields: ["creatorId"])

  videos: [VideoAdverts!] @connection(keyName: "videosByAdvert", fields: ["id"])
  blacklist: [AdvertBlacklist!] @connection(keyName: "blacklistByAdvert", fields: ["id"])

  startDate: AWSDateTime
  endDate: AWSDateTime
}
```

This is my first amplify project and I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement the following use cases:

1. Use a lambda function to query data and return to a client.
2. Use a cron triggered lambda function to make an API call and use a mutation to update some fields.

All I have found so far from googling involves using lambdas to interact with data added via the `amplify storage add` command.

A few other examples I found here on Stackoverflow do not use cognito for auth.

Looks like I will be able to use cloudwatch to trigger lambdas, and so my main problem now is how to actually query and mutate a GraphQL api from a lambda, using cognito for authentication.
Any help would be super helpful, thanks :)

Comment: use `amplify add function` to define a lambda and `@function` to use as a resolver.

Comment: @Alex Got that working, but can't figure out how to authenticate and make queries

Comment: look at this for query and mutation,https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/graphql#function

Answer (score 3):

The key to authenticating your Lambda  functions to interact with your AppSync API is to configure multiple authentication methods.  You are using Cognito for your front end application users, however, you do not want to use that for your Lambda function authentication.  AppSync supports multiple authentications mechanisms for your API.  In your case, you will want to add IAM as the second authentication mechanism.

You can do this from the Amplify CLI:

```
$ amplify update api

Scanning for plugins...
Plugin scan successful

? Please select from one of the below mentioned services: GraphQL

? Choose the default authorization type for the API Amazon Cognito User Pool
Use a Cognito user pool configured as a part of this project.

? Do you want to configure advanced settings for the GraphQL API Yes, I want 
to make some additional changes.

? Configure additional auth types? Yes

? Choose the additional authorization types you want to configure for the API IAM
```

Comment: I am curious why you think we should not use cognito for the lambda function authentication.

As far as I understand, using IAM, you can only control if the user is logged in or not, it doesn't give you the specifics to control what user has access to what data.

Comment: You should use Cognito when authenticating end users to use your API.  You should use IAM when you have backend services (such as Lambda, EC2, ECS, etc...) that want to access your API (use case #2 in the post question).

Comment: I agree, in a majority of the cases. But there would be use cases where you want to use lambda to fetch secrets that need to use APIs, and you want to only allow authenticated users to do that. In that case, I would need the Cognito authentication for the lambda.